# Partner Community Licenses

Tags: community, partner

We have partner community licenses but want to utilize them for our employees. I'm wondering if employees with partner community license can submit records for approval and approve requests based on the org's role hierarchy?

Can approval processes be triggered through a community webpage?

Thanks,

Himu.

Answer (score 1):

**[Set Up Approvals for External Users in Your Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_approvals_for_external_users.htm)**

> Customer and partner users in your community can be assigned as
>   approvers on records or added directly to queues. They can see and
>   take action through the My Approvals and Approval History related
>   lists on the record. Approvals can also be triggered directly from the
>   Chatter feed.
>
> You can now assign role-based external users, such as users with a
>   Customer Community Plus or **[Partner Community license](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_networks_external_users_approvals.htm)**, as approvers on
>   records. You can also add all role-based external users directly to
>   queues and use the queue to assign approvals if you don’t want to
>   assign approvals directly to individual users.

**Note: Users with high volume licenses, such as High Volume Customer Portal and Authenticated Website, can’t approve.**

Comment: Thanks for the response Devendra. You said 'role based external users', can these users be assigned internal org roles? Or does external need to have its own roles?